# Solve conflict b/w carousel slider and menu scripts

Tags: jquery, conflict

**1. This is menu scripts below:**

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/jquery.smartmenus.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**2. This is carousel scripts:**

```
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="jscript"></script>
<script src="../plugins/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the issue? Please provide more code and context

Comment: removing this line `<script src="../plugins/jquery.min.js"></script>` may fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you import 2 different jquery and they conflict.
Try to use jQuery.noConflict(); method 
Here is the api [doc](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)